# Robot.keypress using a Thread: sometimes doesn't focus on the right window

Tags: java, focus, keypress, awtrobot

I'm using a `Robot` instance to programmatically press keys. Those keys are pressed inside a while loop using a class that extends `Thread`.

My app has only one window, the main window.

Even though I request the focus on the correct window every time I press on the button that start the thread, it happens that sometimes the keypress events are launched elsewhere instead of my app.

Why does that happen?

Here's the snippet:

```
try {
            Robot robot = new Robot(); 

            while(!stopped)
            {
               fireRandomKey(robot);
               Thread.sleep(1000);
            }

    } catch (AWTException e) { 
        e.printStackTrace(); 
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your goal is to simulate user interactions, you MUST use Robot to simulate user mouse events (click in a JTextField for example) before sending key events.

That way, you will be immune to outside interactions which can grab you focus (desktop notifications, others apps, etc...)

Comment: The mouse event must be simulated only once (when I press on the button that starts the thread) or every single time a key event is fired in the while loop?

Comment: Everytime a "key listener" (a JTextField for example) must acquire the focus. For example, if you want to simulate a user typing "hello" in a JTexfField, send a mouse click on the JTextfield, and send h,e,l,l,l,o. a sleep of 100ms is good between *every* Robot method calls.